# Are there better ways to plot a continuous scalar function of three variables?

Tags: plotting, color, legending, opacity

I am plotting a continuous scalar function of three variables with this code:

```
function = (
  E^(-((2 (300 + 20 x + x^2 + 20 y + 2 y^2))/(
    4 + t^2))) (E^((2 (100 + 40 x + y^2))/(4 + t^2)) + E^((
     2 (100 + 40 y + y^2))/(4 + t^2)) + 
     2 E^((2 (20 x + (10 + y)^2))/(4 + t^2))
       Cos[(20 t (x - y))/(4 + t^2)]))/(π (4 + t^2));
DensityPlot3D[function, {x, -60, 60}, {y, -60, 60}, {t, 0, 60}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend["Rainbow"], PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

The resulting plot has almost all of the dynamic range hidden below the dark blue blobs at the bottom, while I want to emphasize details of the light purple blobs in the middle and top. The transition between the blue and purple blobs also seems too sharp, and the gray bar alongside the bar legend seems to exclude most of the purple. Are there better ways to plot this function?

Comment: Please include the graphical output next time in cases like these, so people can think about a solution without having to run the code. Especially considering that the code takes a while to run, even on fairly powerful hardware

Comment: There are two good ways, I think. First, you can plot some contours using `ContourPlot3D`. That's how I visualize 3D wavefunctions. Second, you can use a non-linear `OpacityFunction` that allows for more definition in the blobs by cutting down on opacity.

Comment: Playing around with your function, I think you'll have to transform the function to be plotted (plotting e.g. `Log[function + 1*^-5]` gives something a bit more reasonable already). The issue is that `DensityPlot3D` seems to sample very few colors in the interesting region, because all the values there only cover a tiny part of the range of all values

Comment: @LukasLang you can also supply a different non-linear `ColorFunction`

Comment: @b3m2a1 I tried that, but I could never get any resolution in the lobes beyond a certain point. Checking the values supplied to `ColorFunction` (via `Sow`/`Reap`) indicates that the `ColorFunction` is just uniformly sampled ~300 times. So no matter how non-linear the `ColorFunction` is, it seems impossible to get more resolution than that... (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: @b3m2a1 Correction, it's only 101 samples - the other 202 samples of `ColorFunction` are from the `BarLegend`. So the resolution limit is 1% of the value range, which seems rather limited...

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think the way to go would be `ScalingFunctions`, but that doesn't appear to be supported by `DensityPlot3D`...

Comment: @LukasLang probably a lack of `PlotPoints`. Unfortunate that it doesn’t adaptively sample the range...

Comment: @b3m2a can you please show examples of how you visualize 3D wavefunctions and use a non-linear OpacityFunction ?

Comment: Ok, I've checked the code, and the `ColorFunction` is indeed sampled in 100 `0.01` steps before being used (in ``Visualization`Core`VolumePlotPrivate`getColorFunction``). You can turn the sampling off using `Method -> {"SampledColorFunction" -> False}`. I'm not sure that's the whole issue however, I'll keep digging for a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By request, here's an example of how to use a non-linear opacity and color function for some fake wavefunction form (usually I use `ListDensityPlot3D`):

```
pol =
  Thread[{r, θ, φ} -> 
    CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", {x, y, z}][[1]]];
wfn = (E^(r/10))*Simplify[
     ExpToTrig@SphericalHarmonicY[2, 1, θ, φ] -
      ExpToTrig@SphericalHarmonicY[2, -1, θ, φ]
     ] /. pol;

DensityPlot3D[
 Evaluate@wfn,
 {x, -1, 1},
 {y, -1, 1},
 {z, -1, 1},
 OpacityFunction -> (Clip[#^3, {.2, 1}, {0, 1}] &),
 ColorFunction -> (Blend["AvocadoColors", #^3] &)
 ]
```